# Custom page numbers

Tags: page-numbering

I'm writing an article in LaTeX which I will print so that there are two pages per side. I want to number the pages as 1a, 1b, 2a, 2b, 3a, 3b, ... so that the two pages appearing on page 1 will be 1a and 1b, and so on.

Is it possible to do this, for example, using the `fancyhdr` package?

Comment: Wellcome to TeX.SE! Your wanted numbering is unusual. Can you explain why you need it?

Comment: I'm combining two documents; one with ordinary pages and one with, essentially, landscape slides. I will place the landscape "slides" two per portrait page and want to continue numbering as contiguously as possible. So the ordinary document will have page numbers 1, 2, ..., (N-1) and then the "slides", which appear two per page, will be Na, Nb, (N+1)a, (N+1)b, ...

Comment: @SarahBeth: Without your additional comment users would have provided solutions pointing to different directions. You should dd your comment to your OP and perhaps post a screenshot or sketch of your request

Answer (score 3):

The following example defines a counter format command `\abpage` in a similar way as `\arabic`, `\alph`, `\roman`. The command is expandable, thus `\thepage` can be used with `hyperref`, in page references, ... as usual.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\abpage}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@abpage\csname c@#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand*{\@abpage}[1]{%
  \ifodd\numexpr(#1)\relax
    \the\numexpr(1+#1)/2\relax
    a%
  \else
    \the\numexpr(#1)/2\relax
    b%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\abpage{page}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

The example performs the expandable calculations with e-TeX's `\numexpr`. In the quite rare cases, where e-TeX is not available (e.g., ancient TeX systems), package `intcalc` can be used for the expandable integer calculations.

Answer (score 2):

The OP clarified thus:

"So the ordinary document will have page numbers 1, 2, ..., (N-1) and then the "slides", which appear two per page, will be Na, Nb, (N+1)a, (N+1)b, ..."

The following MWE would seem to achieve that result, through a redefinition of `\thepage`, brought about by invocation of `\transitionpagenumbers` which clears the current page under the old numbering system and begins the new numbering system after the `\clearpage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\transitionpagenumbers{
  \clearpage
  \edef\ptran{\thepage}
  \def\pcycle{a}
  \newcounter{falsepage}
  \def\thepage{%
    \setcounter{falsepage}{\numexpr\value{page}-\ptran\relax}%
    \divide\value{falsepage} by 2\relax%
    \addtocounter{falsepage}{\ptran}%
    \arabic{falsepage}\pcycle%
    \if a\pcycle\gdef\pcycle{b}\else\gdef\pcycle{a}\fi%
  }
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-23]
\transitionpagenumbers
\lipsum[1-36]
\end{document}
```

This produces a document with pages 1-5, then 6a, 6b, 7a, 7b, 8a, 8b, and 9a.

Answer (score 1):

The one document with "ordinary page numbers" should be no problem to create, and is therefore excluded from this answer. Also, I assume that stacking landscape pages into a portrait one implies you're using something like an A5 page size for the slides so they'll fit vertically on an A4.

Here's how one could create the slides:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,lipsum,atbegshi,fancyhdr}
\geometry{
  twoside,
  landscape,
  paper=a5paper,
  margin=15mm
}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
\fancyfoot[C]{\theslowpage\ifodd\value{page}a\else b\fi}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcounter{slowpage}\setcounter{slowpage}{1}% Set first slow page
\AtBeginShipout{\ifodd\value{page}\else\stepcounter{slowpage}\fi}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Based on the last page of the previous document, set the value for `slowpage` accordingly. The `slowpage` counter is actually a slave-like counter, only incremented every other page, while the appendix `a` or `b` is conditioned upon the oddness of the regular `page` counter.

The above approach does not mess around with the regular `page` counter, and should therefore not give any troubles with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) or other cross-referencing.